# starting to learn latex and got 3 errors on my compilation

Tags: latex

I'm starting latex and when i wanted to put some links in my document directe to some parts of the documents i got 3 errors that i didn't understand.Can you guys help me to figure out the problem and maybe show the right way to put links thanks.if you need any more infomation i'll be here in a sec (it's for an exam ty alot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
\title{Le LATEX c’est bon, mangez-en}
\author{KHALIL MAZLANI}
\date{mai 2020}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
Depuis la nuit des temps, ou presque, l’humanité a cherché à rendre compte de \underline{vérités universelles}. Parmi les folles formes foisonnantes, nous en retiendrons trois.

\medskip{}

\parindent=0cm \textbf{Déﬁnition 1. Loi zozotérique.} Quelle que soit l’absurdité d’une proposition,il existera toujours au moins 58\% de la population pour y croire.

\medskip{}

\parindent=0cm \textbf{Déﬁnition 2. Loi connectique.} Quelle que soit la population, 1 doute abolit 89 certitudes, et réciproquement.

\medskip{}

\parindent=0cm \textbf{Déﬁnition 3. Loi tactique.} La pataphysique rit.

\medskip{}

\parindent=0cm Dans cet article nous proposons :
\begin{enumerate}
    \item une approche \textbf{énergique} permettant d’aﬃner l’estimation de la propor-tion zozotérique $\Lambda$ (P) en fonction de la proposition

    \item une implémentation Python d’un algorithme de calcul eﬀectif de $\Lambda$ (P).

    \item Le grand oral.
\end{enumerate}
\medskip{}

\parindent=0cm \textbf{Théorème 4.}Étant donnée une proposition P , la proportion zozotérique $\Lambda$ (P)égale sa crédulance relative à la population.

\medskip{}

\hypertarget{théo5}
\parindent=0cm \textbf{Théorème 5.}Soit P op un échantillon de population forte et P une propositionrouge exprimée universellement par quantiﬁcation imbriquée. Alors

$$\Lambda(P) \ge \sum_{58}^{90} \frac{\int_{-237}^{89} \frac{140}{3}-\frac{15e^2}{c \cos(e)} dx}{a-2e \arccos(5)+x- \frac{\pi}{6}+48+ \frac{8x^4}{e}+ \int_{90}^{58} \frac{405 \pi a}{\arctan(9)}+cx+ \frac{e}{x}+9 \tan(a)-7 dx},$$


avec égalité presque sûrement si, et seulement si, P est la proposition « brouillarden matinée, belle et claire journée ».
\medskip{}

\parindent=0cm \textbf{Remarque 6.} La Section \textcolor{red}{\hyperlink{sec2}{2}} contient la démonstration du Théorème \textcolor{red}{\hyperlink{théo5}{5}}.

\medskip{}

\paragraph{}En observant que ce théorème est en fait eﬀectif, nous en déduisons égalementun algorithme de complexité O (n (P)), où n (P) est le nombre de caractèresnécessaire à exprimer P en \textcolor{magenta}{\href{https://lolcode.org/}{Lolcode}}.

\medskip{}

\section{Preuve du Théorème \textcolor{red}{\hyperlink{théo5}{5}}}\hypertarget{sec2}
Les détails sont laissés au lecteur. À la place, révisons un peu nos classiques.
\subsection{Liste des personnages}
\begin{itemize}
    \item[] \textbf{Don Fernand :} premier roi de Castille
    \item[] \textbf{Dona Urraque :} infante de Castille
    \item[] \textbf{Don Diègue :} père de don Rodrigue
    \item[] \textbf{Don Gomès } comte de Gormas et père de Chimène
    \item[] \textbf{Don Rodrigue }: amant de Chimène
    \item[] \textbf{Don Sanche :} amoureux de Chimène
    \item[] \textbf{Don Arias :} gentilhomme castillan
    \item[] \textbf{Don Alonse :} gentilhomme castillan
    \item[] \textbf{Chimène : ﬁlle de don Gomès}
    \item[] \textbf{Léonor :} gouvernante de l’infante
    \item[] \textbf{Elvire :} gouvernante de Chimène
    \item[] \textbf{Le page :} UN PAGE DE L'INFANTE
\end{itemize}
\subsection{Acte 90, scène 237}
\begin{itemize}
        \item[\textbullet] \textbf{DonAlonse}(se faisant féline)\\Rodrigue peut mourir sans hasarder sa gloire ,
        \item[\textbullet] \textbf{DonaUrraque}(défnitif)\\Et je l’entends partout publier hautement
        \item[\textbullet] \textbf{DonArias}(le ton enjoué)\\D’une atteinte imprévue aussi bien que mortelle,
        \item[\textbullet] \textbf{DonDiègue}(se faisant féline)\\Immolez, dis-je, Sire, au bien de tout l’État
        \item[\textbullet] \textbf{DonSanche}(d'une voix rauque)\\Je ne viens point ici demander ma conquête :
        \item[\textbullet] \textbf{DonSanche}(admiratif, quoique jaloux)\\Qui te donne un époux aimé si chèrement.
        \item[\textbullet] \textbf{Lepage}(le ton enjoué)\\Si mon crime par là se peut enfin laver,
        \item[\textbullet] \textbf{DonDiègue}(avec des yeux de merlan frit\\Au nom d’un père mort, ou de notre amitié,
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you could provide the three errors you are getting to make it easier to find a solution

Comment: https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2020/22/1/1590413500-errors.png

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors. Links can break, making the question pointless. See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of points about your code:

- you should load `hyperref` after the other packages (with very few exceptions)
- whenever you find yourself in a situation where you manually insert formatting instructions in your latex document, this is almost always a sign that your are doing something wrong. For example instead of manually formatting and numbering all your theorems and definition, use one of the theorem packages like `amsthm` to have them formatted and numbered automatically
- it is much easier to use latex `\label{}`/`\ref{}` mechanism to automatically insert links then messing with `\hypertarget` etc.
- instead of manually inserting all these `\item[] \textbf{Don Fernand :}`, use a `description` environment instead of the unsuitable `itemize`
- place `\title{}` etc before the document begin to get meaningful pdf meta data
- don't use `$$...$$` for display math. Use either `\[..\]` for unnumbered or `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` for numbered

If one takes all these points into account, the problematic parts causing the errors will have vanished:

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{definition}{Déﬁnition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Théorème}

\title{Le LATEX c’est bon, mangez-en}
\author{KHALIL MAZLANI}
\date{mai 2020}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
Depuis la nuit des temps, ou presque, l’humanité a cherché à rendre compte de \underline{vérités universelles}. Parmi les folles formes foisonnantes, nous en retiendrons trois.

\begin{definition}{Loi zozotérique}
\label{zozo}
Quelle que soit l’absurdité d’une proposition,il existera toujours au moins 58\% de la population pour y croire.
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}{Loi connectique} 
 Quelle que soit la population, 1 doute abolit 89 certitudes, et réciproquement.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}{}
\label{foo}
Soit P op un échantillon de population forte et P une propositionrouge exprimée universellement par quantiﬁcation imbriquée. Alors
\[
\Lambda(P) \ge \sum_{58}^{90} \frac{\int_{-237}^{89} \frac{140}{3}-\frac{15e^2}{c \cos(e)} dx}{a-2e \arccos(5)+x- \frac{\pi}{6}+48+ \frac{8x^4}{e}+ \int_{90}^{58} \frac{405 \pi a}{\arctan(9)}+cx+ \frac{e}{x}+9 \tan(a)-7 dx},
\]

avec égalité presque sûrement si, et seulement si, P est la proposition « brouillarden matinée, belle et claire journée ».
\end{theorem}


\section{Preuve du Théorème \ref{foo}}
\label{sec2}

Les détails sont laissés au lecteur. À la place, révisons un peu nos classiques.
\subsection{Liste des personnages}
\begin{description}
    \item[Don Fernand :] premier roi de Castille
    \item[Dona Urraque :] infante de Castille
\end{description}


\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mentu You're welcome! May I suggest a couple of good latex book? https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/

Comment: @Mentu Also in case you are interested in a French Q&A site about latex: https://texnique.fr/osqa/